# jointjs vertice don't drag correctly on mobile

Tags: jointjs

Vertices don't move correctly (drag) on mobile phone whereas it's ok on pc.
This is a simple example where the bug can be observed.

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
el: $('#easel'),
width: 600,
height: 200,
gridSize: 1,
model: graph
});

var parent = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
position: {x: 100,y: 30},
size: {width: 100,height: 30},
attrs: {rect: {fill: 'blue'},
        text: {text: 'parent',fill: 'white'}}
});
var child = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
position: {x: 70,y: 130},
size: {width: 70,height: 30},
attrs: {rect: {fill: 'lightgreen',rx: 5,ry: 5},
        text: {text: 'child',fill: 'white'}}
});

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
source: {id: parent.id},
target: {id: child.id},
vertices: [{x: 210,y: 75}, {x: 190,y: 105}]
});

graph.addCells([parent, child, link]);
```

Does anyone have an idea?